# Excel Microsoft Query parameter length limit

Tags: sql-server, excel

MS Excel 2010 64-bit
Windows 7 Pro 64-bit on the local machine
SQL Server 2012

I often call stored procedures in SQL Server to return data to Excel for analysis in PivotTables. I pass parameters to the sp's using the following syntax in Microsoft Query's SQL Editor:

```
{Call dbo.MySP(?,?,?,)}
```

Where `dbo.MySP` is an SP that takes three parameters. When I return the output from the query to Excel I get to select which cells to refer to to get the parameter values.

Yesterday I wrote an SP that takes 3 arguments: a date, another date and a text string delimited by commas. The SP has them declared as two `DATETIMES` and an `NVARCHAR(4000)`. As usual, I convert the dates in Excel to text strings in the form `yyyy-mm-dd` to pass them, but the text string is just a string of characters with individual values delimited by a pipe (`|`).

When I attempt to select the cell containing a text string less than `255` characters all is well. If I go over `255` I get an error from Excel complaining:

> Bad parameter type. Microsoft Excel was expecting a different kind of
>   value that was was provided.

Changing the delimiter has no impact.

- Is that a hard limit on the length a parameter passed from Excel can handle?
- Is there a workaround of any sort?

Note that is is clearly an Excel limitation, running the same query with any length parameter works fine in SSMS.

Comment: An alternative method is to call the SP's from VBA using `CreateParamater` and `AppendParameter`.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am seeing the same problem.